# How to activate bootstrap modal next and back buttons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to upgrade this multi step form so the back and next buttons sit in the footer of this modal. How do I go about moving them there? (i.e. the next button in RED) - It doesn't work clicking this.

Thank you

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var navListItems = $('div.setup-panel div a'),
    allWells = $('.setup-content'),
    allNextBtn = $('.nextBtn'),
    allPrevBtn = $('.prevBtn');

  allWells.hide();

  navListItems.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
      $item = $(this);

    if (!$item.hasClass('disabled')) {
      navListItems.removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-default');
      $item.addClass('btn-primary');
      allWells.hide();
      $target.show();
      $target.find('input:eq(0)').focus();
    }
  });

  allPrevBtn.click(function() {
    var curStep = $(this).closest(".setup-content"),
      curStepBtn = curStep.attr("id"),
      prevStepWizard = $('div.setup-panel div a[href="#' + curStepBtn + '"]').parent().prev().children("a");

    prevStepWizard.trigger('click');
  });

  allNextBtn.click(function() {
    var curStep = $(this).closest(".setup-content"),
      curStepBtn = curStep.attr("id"),
      nextStepWizard = $('div.setup-panel div a[href="#' + curStepBtn + '"]').parent().next().children("a"),
      curInputs = curStep.find("input[type='text'],input[type='url']"),
      isValid = true;

    $(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
    for (var i = 0; i < curInputs.length; i++) {
      if (!curInputs[i].validity.valid) {
        isValid = false;
        $(curInputs[i]).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
      }
    }

    if (isValid)
      nextStepWizard.removeAttr('disabled').trigger('click');
  });

  $('div.setup-panel div a.btn-primary').trigger('click');
});
```

```css
body {
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.stepwizard-step p {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.stepwizard-row {
  display: table-row;
}
.stepwizard {
  display: table;
  width: 90%;
  position: relative;
}
.stepwizard-step button[disabled] {
  opacity: 1 !important;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100) !important;
}
.stepwizard-row:before {
  top: 14px;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  content: " ";
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  z-order: 0;
}
.stepwizard-step {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.btn-circle {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
.modal-body {
  max-height: calc(100vh - 210px);
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.modal-dialog {
  min-width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <div class="stepwizard">
          <div class="stepwizard-row setup-panel">
            <div class="stepwizard-step">
              <a href="#step-1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle">1</a>
              <p>Student Details</p>
            </div>
            <div class="stepwizard-step">
              <a href="#step-2" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" disabled="disabled">2</a>
              <p>Student Medical</p>
            </div>
            <div class="stepwizard-step">
              <a href="#step-3" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" disabled="disabled">3</a>
              <p>Primary Contact</p>
            </div>
            <div class="stepwizard-step">
              <a href="#step-4" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" disabled="disabled">4</a>
              <p>Secondary Contact</p>
            </div>
            <div class="stepwizard-step">
              <a href="#step-5" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" disabled="disabled">5</a>
              <p>Review & Submit</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="container" style="width:100%;">



          <form role="form" action="" method="post">
            <div class="row setup-content" id="step-1">
              <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button">Next</button>
                  <h3> Step 1</h3>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
                    <input maxlength="100" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter First Name" type="text">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Last Name</label>
                    <input maxlength="100" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Last Name" type="text">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Address</label>
                    <textarea required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your address"></textarea>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row setup-content" id="step-2">
              <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <h3> Step 2</h3>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Company Name</label>
                    <input maxlength="200" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Name" type="text">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Company Address</label>
                    <input maxlength="200" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Address" type="text">
                  </div>
                  <button class="btn btn-primary prevBtn btn-lg pull-left" type="button">Back</button>
                  <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button">Next</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row setup-content" id="step-3">
              <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <h3> Step 3</h3>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Company Name</label>
                    <input maxlength="200" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Name" type="text">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Company Address</label>
                    <input maxlength="200" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Address" type="text">
                  </div>
                  <button class="btn btn-primary prevBtn btn-lg pull-left" type="button">Back</button>
                  <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button">Next</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row setup-content" id="step-4">
              <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <h3> Step 4</h3>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Company Name</label>
                    <input maxlength="200" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Name" type="text">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Company Address</label>
                    <input maxlength="200" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Address" type="text">
                  </div>
                  <button class="btn btn-primary prevBtn btn-lg pull-left" type="button">Back</button>
                  <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button">Next</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row setup-content" id="step-5">
              <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <h3> Step 5</h3>
                  <button class="btn btn-primary prevBtn btn-lg pull-left" type="button">Back</button>
                  <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg pull-right" type="submit">Submit</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary prevBtn btn-lg pull-left" type="button">Back</button>
        <button style="color:red;" class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button">Next</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now your prev and next buttons are working

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var navListItems = $('div.setup-panel div a'),
          allWells = $('.setup-content'),
          allNextBtn = $('.nextBtn'),
      allPrevBtn = $('.prevBtn');

  allWells.hide();

  navListItems.click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
              $item = $(this);

      if (!$item.hasClass('disabled')) {
          navListItems.removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-default');
          $item.addClass('btn-primary');
          allWells.hide();
          $target.show();
          $target.find('input:eq(0)').focus();
      }
  });
  
  allPrevBtn.click(function(){
      var setupwizard = $('.stepwizard-row');
      var sel = setupwizard.find('.btn-primary');
      var to_sel = sel.parent().prev().find('.btn-circle');
      to_sel.trigger('click');
    
      /* DISABLING AND ENABLING PREV AND NEXT
         BUTTONS BASED ON CURRENT PAGE
      */
      if(to_sel.hasClass('start-class'))
      {
         $('.prevBtn').addClass('disabled-control');
         $('.nextBtn').removeClass('disabled-control');
      }
      else if(to_sel.hasClass('end-class'))
      {
         $('.nextBtn').addClass('disabled-control');
         $('.prevBtn').removeClass('disabled-control');
      }
      else
      {
         $('.nextBtn').removeClass('disabled-control');
         $('.prevBtn').removeClass('disabled-control');
      }
    
  });



$(document).on('click', '.nextBtn', function(){
      var setupwizard = $('.stepwizard-row');
      var sel = setupwizard.find('.btn-primary');
      var to_sel = sel.parent().next().find('.btn-circle');
      var err = 0;

      var step = get_current_page_id();

      /* CHECKING IF ALL INPUTS AND TEXTAREA IN THE CURRENT 
         PAGE ARE FILLED. IF NOT : ADD ERROR CLASS ON INPUT 
         AND INCREMENT ERROR COUNTER */
      $('#' + step + ' input, textarea').each(function(){
          if($(this).val() == '')
          {   
               if(!$(this).hasClass('error-class'))
                   $(this).addClass('error-class')

              err++;
          }
          else
          {
               if($(this).hasClass('error-class'))
                   $(this).removeClass('error-class')
          }
      });

      /* IF ERROR COUNTER == 0 ( ie. NO ERRORS FOUND )
             => PROCEED TO NEXT STEP 
      */
      if(err == 0)
      {
          to_sel.trigger('click');
  
          if(to_sel.hasClass('start-class'))
          {
             $('.prevBtn').addClass('disabled-control');
             $('.nextBtn').removeClass('disabled-control');
          }
          else if(to_sel.hasClass('end-class'))
          {
              $('.nextBtn').addClass('disabled-control');
              $('.prevBtn').removeClass('disabled-control');
          }
          else
          {
              $('.nextBtn').removeClass('disabled-control');
              $('.prevBtn').removeClass('disabled-control');
          }
      }
  });

 /* SHOW AND HIDE ERROR CLASS AS USER TYPES */
 $(document).on('input', 'input, textarea', function(){
    if($(this).val() == '')
    {
         if(!$(this).hasClass('error-class'))
            $(this).addClass('error-class');
    }
    else
    {
        if($(this).hasClass('error-class'))
            $(this).removeClass('error-class')
    }
});

  /* FUNCTION WHICH RETURNS THE ID OF CURRENT VISIBLE PAGE */
  function get_current_page_id()
  {
      return $(".setup-content:visible").attr('id');
  }

  $('div.setup-panel div a.btn-primary').trigger('click');
});
```

```css
body {
    margin-top:40px;
}
.stepwizard-step p {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.stepwizard-row {
    display: table-row;
}
.stepwizard {
    display: table;
    width: 90%;
    position: relative;
}
.stepwizard-step button[disabled] {
    opacity: 1 !important;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100) !important;
}
.stepwizard-row:before {
    top: 14px;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    content: " ";
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    z-order: 0;
}
.stepwizard-step {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
.btn-circle {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 6px 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.428571429;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
.modal-body {
    max-height: calc(100vh - 210px);
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.disabled-control{
      opacity: 0.4; 
      cursor: not-allowed;
      pointer-events: none;
    }

.modal-dialog {
   
    min-width: 70%;
 
 }

.error-class{
    border: 1px solid red !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <div class="stepwizard">
    <div class="stepwizard-row setup-panel">
      <div class="stepwizard-step">
        <a href="#step-1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle start-class">1</a>
        <p>Student Details</p>
      </div>
      <div class="stepwizard-step">
        <a href="#step-2" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" disabled="disabled">2</a>
        <p>Student Medical</p>
      </div>
      <div class="stepwizard-step">
        <a href="#step-3" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" disabled="disabled">3</a>
        <p>Primary Contact</p>
      </div>
      <div class="stepwizard-step">
        <a href="#step-4" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" disabled="disabled">4</a>
        <p>Secondary Contact</p>
      </div>
      <div class="stepwizard-step">
        <a href="#step-5" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle end-class" disabled="disabled">5</a>
        <p>Review & Submit</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                   <div class="container" style="width:100%;">
  

  
  <form role="form" action="" method="post">
    <div class="row setup-content" id="step-1">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button">Next</button><h3> Step 1</h3>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
            <input maxlength="100" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter First Name" type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Last Name</label>
            <input maxlength="100" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Last Name" type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Address</label>
            <textarea required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your address"></textarea>
          </div>
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row setup-content" id="step-2">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h3> Step 2</h3>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Company Name</label>
            <input maxlength="200" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Name" type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Company Address</label>
            <input maxlength="200" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Address" type="text">
          </div>
          <button class="btn btn-primary prevBtn btn-lg pull-left disabled-control" type="button">Back</button>
          <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button">Next</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row setup-content" id="step-3">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h3> Step 3</h3>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Company Name</label>
            <input maxlength="200" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Name" type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Company Address</label>
            <input maxlength="200" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Address" type="text">
          </div>
          <button class="btn btn-primary prevBtn btn-lg pull-left disabled-control" type="button">Back</button>
          <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button">Next</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row setup-content" id="step-4">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h3> Step 4</h3>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Company Name</label>
            <input maxlength="200" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Name" type="text">
           </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Company Address</label>
            <input maxlength="200" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Address" type="text">
          </div>
          <button class="btn btn-primary prevBtn btn-lg pull-left disabled-control" type="button">Back</button>
          <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button">Next</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row setup-content" id="step-5">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h3> Step 5</h3>
          <button class="btn btn-primary prevBtn btn-lg pull-left disabled-control" type="button">Back</button>
          <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg pull-right" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  
</div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary prevBtn btn-lg pull-left disabled-control" type="button">Back</button>
    <button style="color:red;" class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button">Next</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: Nice. Thank you. How do I maintain the validation check on next?

Comment: Updated my answer. added validation on buttons

Comment: Hi, in step 1 it doesn't seem to alert if first name and surname are blank. I refreshed browser cache.

Comment: oh and clicking the buttons for each step in the header is progressing even though it is disabled. It should only allow progress or return via those buttons if form is valid and change of step using these doesn't update back button disabled/enabled.

Comment: @mrid Thank you so much! I don't suppose you would know how to get the step links (when you click on 1, 2, 3, 4, 5) to follow the validation rules? For example when on Step 1 you should not be able to click step 2, 3, 4, or 5 which at the moment you can. But when on step 2 you are allowed to go back to step 1 but you can only return to step 2 so long as you don't un-validate / clear data in fields in step 1.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem I guess...I'll modify the code